# Explore the memory with only a void pointer

Tags: c, pointers, pixel, void

I'm starting with the C language (I usually work with Java or PHP), and I have a problem with the void* pointer type.

In my program, I get a pixel buffer from an external API contains in the structure *f*.
    (void*) f -> pixbuf

This pointer points to a pixel buffer coded in BGR24. 3 bytes corresponds to a pixel (1 byte per color).

I want to keep only 1 octet by pixel (pixel = 3 bytes). But I really don't know how to do it. I juste have the addresse (f -> pixbuf) of all these octets. Is it possible to fill a char tab by reading each octet one by one ?

PS: The size of f -> pixelbuf is 5 292 000 bytes

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly, are you saying you want to convert the image to 8 bit color?

Comment: You can cast it to e.g. an `unsigned char*` so you can then read octets one-by-one. But that sounds like your library doesn't intend you to do that, if it gives you a void back instead.

Comment: Are you saying you want to re-encode the colour from 24 bit BGR into 8 bit rgb with 3 bits for red and green and 2 bits for blue?

Comment: Yes I want to convert an image from 24bits to 8bits. The images are grey so I don't need 3pixels. But I only have the pointer to the pixel buffer,  a void* pointer.

Comment: @LaurentJerber Wait, so just to clarify one more time, you want to turn it into just a single 8 bit graymap? Losing the colour data and therefore shrinking the image by 2 thirds?

Comment: Exactly, it's an IR image and the B,  G,  and R values are identical.

Comment: one possibility, extract every 3rd byte into a new buffer.  Or, using two pointers into the current buffer, then you could copy every third byte into a much short sequence of single bytes  where the first byte would not change, the second byte of the new sequence would be f[3] --> f[1], f[6] --> f[2]. etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this :

```
int length =  f->pixbuflen;
unsigned char* sourcepixels = (unsigned char*)f->pixbuf;
unsigned char* destpixels = malloc(length / 3); // length being the number of
                                                // RGB pixels of the original image
for (int i = 0; i < length/3; i++)
  destpixels[i] = sourcepixels[i*3];
```

This is non optimized, non tested, non error checking  code.

Comment: I didn't know we could explore like an array a unsigned char pointer. I'll try it tomorrow (I'm not at work now)  because I know the length from the variable f - > pixbuflen

Comment: @LaurentJerber arrays don't really exist in C. `x[i]` is actually shorthand for `*(x + i)`.

Comment: "*arrays don't really exist in C*" What?

Comment: @MichaelWalz arrays do exist and they are different from pointers although one can be converted to the other :)

Comment: @Drax OK, they exist but basically it boils down to pointers.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I used to think like this before the day i tried to cast a `char[][]` to `char**`, then i just definitely removed from my mind that "arrays boils down to pointers" and discovered the ultimate freedom of C that most zen warriors have sought in the lost mountains without ever discovering it.

Comment: @Drax : sure because `char**` is a pointer to pointer to `char` and `char p[][WIDTH]` is syntactic sugar that allows you to write `p[x][y]` instead of  `*(p + x + y * WIDTH)`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz It's a little more than syntactic sugar, the sizeof an array and pointers have very different rules for example, but anyway you seem to know that already so this discussion doesn't have much point, except maybe for some random internet guy reading this comments and getting an 'aha!' moment.

Comment: Worked perfectly! 

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 2):

To access a specific data type via a `void`-pointer you need to cast the `void`-pointer to a pointer of the type you want to access, `char` in your case.

```
struct pic
{
  void * pixbuf;
  size_t pixbuflen;
  ...
}

...

struct pic f = ...;
struct pic grey = {0};

grey->pixbuflen = f->pixbuflen/3;
grey->pixbuf = malloc(grey->pixbuflen); /* Allocate the target buffer begin sized a 
                                          3rd of the destination buffer. */
if (NULL == grey->pixbuf) /* Test for failure. */
{
   /* Failure to allocate the buffer. */
   grey->pixbuflen = 0;
   exit(1);
}

for (size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < grey->pixbuflen; ++i, j += 3)
{
  ((char *) grey->pixbuf)[i] = ((char *) f->pixbuf)[j]; /* Copy every 3rd byte from 
                                                           source to destination. */
}
```

If you can make sure a pointer points to valid memory, you can index it like an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct pixel
{
  char b;
  char g;
  char r;
}              pixel_t;
```

Then you can access any color for any pixel you want like this:

```
pixel_t*  pixels = f->pixbuf;

pixels[42].r = 0x0F;
pixels[42].g = 0xA0;
pixels[42].b = 0xB4;
```

Comment: Does this not suffer from (theoretical) padding issues? It would probably be better to use an array of arrays. (char[N][3])

Comment: @Vality there is no problem issue, char is the smallest variable there is so it will be shrinked as possible, any overload will be in array or packed attr declared

Comment: It will create an array of pixel (the structure).  Each structure containing the 3 bytes?

Comment: @LaurentJerber Yes, then it's up to you to use whatever algorithm you want to transform those 3 bytes into 1.

Comment: @Vality In theory yes, there is no perfect guarantee that this struct will have alignement of 1. You could always add your favourite compiler attribute to make it `packed`.